# Java make jar file

Tags: java, jar

Given the following class:

```
public class Menu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

I want to run jar file, but after I create it I click on `menu.jar` but it doesn't run. Why is this?

Comment: What else have you accomplished? This is a *VERY* simple program.

Comment: How did you create the Jar? Did you create an executable jar ?

Comment: yes, Type:Executable Jar File

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't run? If you are double clicking on the jar from Explorer/Finder then any console output will be swallowed by the OS. What do you expect to see?

Comment: Did you include a manifest? If so, what does it look like? If not, add one.

Comment: System.out.println is printing the string onto the commandline, if you didn't start your program from the commandline, you probably will not see the output.

Comment: Instead of `System.out.println("hi")`, try `javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is running.")` or something similar, that doesn't rely on console input.

Answer (score 3):

If you double click a jar file `javaw` is used to launch the jar file. The main difference between `java` and `javaw` is that the later isn't attached to a console, so you won't ever see the output of your `System.out.println` statement.

You can try on of these two things:

### 1. Create a frame instead

```
import javax.swing.*; 

public class Menu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Hi!" ); 
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE ); 
                frame.setVisible( true ); 
            }
        } ); 
    }
}
```

### 2. Run the jar from the console (without double clicking)

```
$> java -jar your-file.jar
hi
```

Comment: Plus, unless I've misunderstood the OPs question, I don't see any requirement for it to be a GUI app; seems like they simply want something that can print to the console, at the very least.

Comment: @BoristheSpider you are correct. sorry, i was being sloppy.

Comment: @PaulRichter i was reading between the lines. if you want to "click on a jar", as the OP put it, then you'll usually need a gui to indicate to the user that the application was indeed launched.

Comment: Fair enough; seems like a few people also had that thought as well. I was mainly concerned with giving the OP information about something the OP didn't directly ask for or allude to.

Answer (score 2):

Follow instruction described at page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

First of all you need to have Manifest.FM file in META-INF folder and in mentioned file you need to set Main-Class: classname

Answer (score 1):

#### Creating Jars

When you create a `.jar` file, you have to make sure that the `.jar` file knows which program to run. This is done by a `Main-Class` entry in a `MANIFEST.MF` file in a `META-INF` folder inside the `.jar` file. Newer versions of the `jar` tool support option `-e` to do the job.

The following `Makefile` shows how to run the various commands:

```
.PHONY: all
all: run

.PHONY: run
run: Hello.jar
        java -jar Hello.jar

Hello.jar: Hello.class
        jar cvfe Hello.jar Hello Hello.class

Hello.class: Hello.java
        javac Hello.java
```

Please note that `Makefile`s are not the typical way to build and run Java programs. I only used a `Makefile` here because for its convenience of showing the bare metal commands that are executed for the different things. Usually one would use *Apache Maven* `mvn`, *Apache Ant* `ant` or `gradle` for automating the construction process of Java applications.

#### Running Jars

When you run a `.jar` file, depending on where you start it (i.e. Windows Explorer), it might actually have no terminal attached. `System.out` is the `stdout` of the JVM process, and if it is not attached to a terminal, the message will not be visible on the screen, it will go to nowhere (`NIL:` on Windows, `/dev/null` on UNIX).

There are two options:

- Start the jar file from a terminal, i.e. run `cmd.exe` or `xterm` or something like that, and run the jar file there, using `cd *dirOfJarFile*` then `java -jar *menu.jar*`.
- Use a GUI instead.

I recommend the first option for now.

#### GUI sample code

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloSwing {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello");
        frame.getContentPane.add(new JLabel("Hello, world!"));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD.exe on Windows or terminal on Mac and type the following code:

```
java -jar path-to-your-jar-file.jar
```

For example:

```
java -jar C:\MyAwesomeJarFile.jar
```

It should print `Hi` in the console.